# Need a few tips on calling methods and fields in abstract way

Tags: java, reflection, invoke

Well I have this method, where I'm not sure how to handle a part of it, it's where the comment starts with exclamation marks: "// !!!! this is the part that concerns me..."

```
public Person getPersonFromRS(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, NoSuchMethodException,
    IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
{
  Person person = new Person();

  // getting the fiels and methods of the class Person
  Field[] fields = person.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
  Method[] methods = Person.class.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
  String setter = "set";

  // just ignoring these fields of the class
  for (Field field : fields) {
    if (field.getName().equals("nul") || field.getName().equals("pairMarriages")
        || field.getName().equals("pairMarriage_Date") || field.getName().equals("pairBiography")) {
      continue;
    }

    // getting the value from resultSet as string
    String value = "";
    try {
      value = rs.getString(field.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Error with getting the column " + field.getName() + " from database");
      continue;
    }

    // if value is not null and the string inside not NULL, set the value to the person
    if (!(value == null))
      System.out.println("THE RETRIEVED VALUE: " + value);

    if ((!(value == null)) && !value.equals(nul)) {
      // methodName = setParameter
      String methodName = setter + field.getName();
      System.out.println("\nmethod Name: " + methodName);

      Method method = null;
      try {
        System.out.println("The field type is " + field.getType());
        method = person.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, field.getType());
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        continue;
      }

      // !!!! this is the part that concerns me, what's the best way to handle this part in order
      // to avoid this flood for every type?
      // determining the type of the value to set in
      Type type = field.getType();
      if (field.getType() == String.class) {
        method.invoke(person, value);
      } else if (field.getType() == long.class) {
        method.invoke(person, Long.parseLong(value));
      } else if (field.getType() == int.class) {
        method.invoke(person, Integer.parseInt(value));
      } else if (field.getType() == PersonDate.class) {
        PersonDate date = new PersonDate(value);
        method.invoke(person, date);
      }
    }
  }
  return person;
}
```

Is there an optimal way to do that, without handling every single argument type like this? I mean this seems like overhead to me?

Comment: *"this seems like overhead to me?"*  How does it seem to a profiler?

Comment: It might be time to use JPA (Java Persistence API)? JPA provides automatic mapping of database values to Java objects.

Answer (score 1):

A switch statement would be cleaner, but unless you want to throw in a real ORM solution like JDO, JPA, hibernate, whatever.. you're going to have to do it. What's your concern? If when you say "overhead" you mean CPU cycles, then you should be more concerned about all of the reflection you're doing rather than a bunch of if/else statements. If your concern is maintenance, yeah, it's going to be a lot of code. That said, if you're only mapping a dozen or so types... it's not really a big deal. There aren't really any shortcuts here other than using an off the shelf ORM tool.

Comment: Sorry, I meant overhead as overhead for me writing that this time. ;) Thanks a lot to all of you, excellent answers showing me paths I might use next time I come across any task like this.
Another question - are reflections that hard on CPU?

Comment: They certainly aren't easy on it... but it's all relative. Dynamic languages like groovy use reflection extensively as does Spring. With Spring it's mostly at application start time, so it's not really noticeable at runtime. With groovy it's one of the reasons it's a lot slower than vanilla java.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a map first from the `ResultSet`. This `map` contains the column names with their corresponding value.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
    map.put(metaData.getColumnName(column), rs.getString(column));
}
return map;
```

Then you could use this `map` to *`populate`* an instance of `Person`. This will require using the `populate` method of [`BeanUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) class, which is part of [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/).

```
Person person = new Person();
BeanUtils.populate(person, map);
```

This class has:

> Utility methods for populating JavaBeans properties via reflection.

You can modify your query as you want to fill the fields you need.